# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH - Failed load javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, maven, tomcat

I imported a project for Eclipse that uses Spring MVC and maven and performed in Tomcat 8 and get this error in the browser when I try to load a javascript file in the JSP page:
GET http://localhost:8080/edp-data/ext/src/app/application.js?_dc=1425406963138 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

I've tried to correct in various ways with various solutions of the Internet, changing the server.xml tomcat, permission of files and folders and several other attempts without success.

Could anyone help me?

Thank's!

Comment: Thx, but not helps :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reverted back to Tomcat 7. Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Thanks for ur guide. I have solved such a issue but I don't know why.